# z-index is canceled by setting transform(rotate)

Tags: css, z-index, transform

Using transform property, z-index is canceled and appeared in the front.
(When commenting out -webkit-transform, z-index is properly working in below code)

```css
.test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.test:after {
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #999;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>transform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="transformtest.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test">z-index is canceled.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

How do transform and z-index work together?

Comment: This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/KmnF2/) I made, Do you want to hide the text with z-index?

Comment: Working fine http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/8MQkP/ what is the doubt actually?

Comment: Thank you for making fiddle. I want to show the shadow behind text rectangle (like a post-it).

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Let's walk through what is occurring.  To start, note that `z-index` on positioned elements and `transform` by itself create new "[stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)" on elements.  Here's what's going on:

Your `.test` element has `transform` set to something other than none, which gives it its own stacking context.

You then add a `.test:after` pseudo-element, which is a child of `.test`.  This child has `z-index: -1`, setting the stack level of `.test:after` **within the stacking context of `.test`**  Setting `z-index: -1` on `.test:after` does not place it behind `.test` because `z-index` only has meaning within a given stacking context.

When you remove `-webkit-transform` from `.test` it removes its stacking context, causing `.test` and `.test:after` to share a stacking context (that of `<html>`) and making `.test:after` go behind `.test`.  Note that after removing `.test`'s `-webkit-transform` rule you can, once again, give it its own stacking context by setting a new `z-index` rule (any value) on `.test` (again, because it is positioned)!

**So how do we solve your problem?**

To get z-index working the way you expect, make sure that `.test` and `.test:after` share the same stacking context.  The problem is that you want `.test` rotated with transform, but to do so means creating its own stacking context.  Fortunately, placing `.test` in a wrapping container and rotating that will still allow its children to share a stacking context while also rotating both.

- Here's what you started with: http://jsfiddle.net/fH64Q/
- And here's a way you can get around the stacking-contexts and keep
  the rotation (note that the shadow gets a bit cut off because of `.test`'s white background):

```css
.wrapper {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
}
.test {
       width: 150px;
       height: 40px;
       margin: 30px;
       line-height: 40px;
       position: relative;
       background: white;
}
.test:after {
       width: 100px;
       height: 35px;
       content: "";
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 2px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #999; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
       transform: rotate(3deg);
       z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test">z-index is canceled.</div>
</div>
```

There are other ways to do this, better ways even.  I would probably make the "post-it" background the containing element and then put the text inside, that would probably be the easiest method and would reduce the complexity of what you have.

Check out [this article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) for more details about `z-index` and stacking order, or [the working W3C CSS3 spec on stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-positioning-20120207/#det-stacking-context)

Comment: This was a great explanation of one of the most complex aspects of CSS layout. For future reading, [check the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html)

Comment: Fantastic explanation. I was using `transform` on my parent element and was wondering why my `::before` element was not stacked behind the parent.

Comment: I am using it in the pseudo-element, and I can't make it keeps its `z-index` value.

Comment: If you are running into this because you want to stack something above a rotated element, you can hack it by rotating that something by 0 degrees. This is sufficient to make a new stacking context, but has no visual impact. I haven't done any analysis to see if there's a performance impact.

Answer (score 29):

Set the div you want to stay on top to `position:relative`

Comment: It worked for me. Is it related with the stacks context mentioned above? If someone can help to clarify it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe it's to do with when you have a position of relative (or absolute) and a z-index set, a new stacking context is created?

Comment: Thanks for this! Worked like a charm after trying to set CSS for elements that are not selected of the same class!!

Answer (score 11):

Had a similar problem where siblings were being `transform: translate()`'d and `z-index` wouldn't work.

Most straightforward solution is to set `position: relative` on all siblings, then `z-index` would work again.

Comment: I suppose this would create a new stacking context for each sibling and therefore the `z-index` would only work within the parent but can not overlap the parent's siblings, correct? At least that's what I'm struggling to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

Quick fix: You could just rotate the other element by 0 degrees as well.

Comment: This worked for me in a case where I could not rotate the container

Comment: I was having a strange problem with z-index not being observed, and then applying the style `transform:rotate(0.0rad)` fixed it. I could not apply it via a css rule, it had to be directly on the element. This makes NO sense, but thanks for posting the answer that made me try it.

Answer (score 6):

For those who still looking for the solution, I found this article how to solve issue with `transform` and `z-index` [here](https://katydecorah.com/code/z-index-and-transform)

Simple usage of it is by doing this:

```
.parent { transform-style: preserve-3d; }
.parent:before { transform: translateZ(-1em); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar problem.
What i did was, I added a wrapper div around the test and gave the transform property to the wrapper div.

```
.wrapper{
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KmnF2/16/

Answer (score -4):

Set the div you want to stay on top to position:absolute