# Shadow with CSS "after" pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, z-index, pseudo-element

I wish like to place a curved shadow under my DIV-Container if i hover on the DIV. Unfortunately the shadow is above my box and not below. Any suggestions?

This is my CSS:

```
.appointment {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.appointment:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.appointment:hover:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #000000;
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="appointment">
    <div class="desc">
        <div class="app-date">07.10.2014</div>
        <div class="app-location">Bamberg, Bayern</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="appointment" >
    <div class="desc">
        <div class="app-date">08.10.2014</div>
        <div class="app-location">Hamburg, Hamburg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yw035wz8/3)

It should look like this:
[image: Curved Shadow]

Comment: There is a fiddle available illustrating the problem.

Comment: Hope this Fiddle can explain it: http://jsfiddle.net/yw035wz8/3/

Comment: This would be easier done by dropping the `::after` and just using `hover` and `box-shadow`.

Comment: Put a z-index on your `.desc` element instead of on `.appointment`.

Comment: The problem is: transform: scale(1.1); on appointment:hover, it work's if it get's removed.

Comment: But i need curved shadow @RemySheppard. That's not possible with box-shadow.

Comment: What is a curved shadow?

Comment: I create an image for that

Comment: @alexP - you mean like [these](http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects)? Because it is possible.

Comment: It now seems this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472802/css-z-index-lost-after-webkit-transform-translate3d

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20852489/2328888 that answer might help you.

Comment: Exactly @RemySheppard, but these are pseudo-elemnts

Comment: @Remy Sheppard They are using :after and :before.

Comment: So is @alexP in his fiddle? Also: What about guy who suggested z-index? Let's give that some ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer: [z-index canceled by transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate/20852489#20852489) you need to change your markup.

```
  <div class="appointment-wrapper">
    <div class="appointment">
        <div class="desc">
            <div class="app-date">07.10.2014</div>
            <div class="app-location">Bamberg, Bayern</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and then use transform: scale(1.1) on the appointment-wrapper.

```
.appointment-wrapper:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

This way `.appointment` and it's pseudo elements share the same stacking context.

**EDIT**: Be aware that the pseudo elements get transformed aswell.

Comment: Just a point of contention: this doesn't give a curve. It just rotates a straight edge.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, you sure are right, I just took alexPs approach and tried to fix it.