# Using pseudoelements for box-shadow, z-index behavior

Tags: css

I use a `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements to create a custom-shaped shadow on my text card. I use css like this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71thws1a/)):

```
.card {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    float: left; 
    width: 310px; 
    height: 310px; 
    text-align: center;     
    color: black; 
    padding-top: 35px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.card h1 {
    font-size: 15px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    line-height: 17px; 
    font-style: italic; 
    margin: 0;
}

.card .text { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    margin: 8px auto; 
    padding: 15px 10px; 
    font-size: 13px; 
    text-align: left; 
    line-height: 14px; 
    height: 170px; 
    width: 280px; 
    background: white; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    position: relative; 
    color: #222222; 
}
.card .text:before, 
.card .text:after { 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
    content: ""; 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: -1; 
    top: 50%; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 40px; 
    right: 40px; 
    border-radius: 100px/10px; 
}
.card .text:after {
    -webkit-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
    transform: skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
    right: 10px; left: auto; 
}
```

So far so good. Problems start, when i add some background to my `.card` element, for example `background: #0aabff` ([jsFiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/71thws1a/1/)). Notice, pseudo-elements shadow around `.text` disappeared.

I tried solving this by adding `z-index` to my `.text` element, but then, instead of being behind my `.text` element, my `:before, :after` are displayed before it, despite having a `z-index: -1;` property ([jsFiddle #3](http://jsfiddle.net/71thws1a/2/)).

This makes little sense to me, and i still don't know how to solve this kind of problem. Perhaps, there is some kind of workaround, or another way to get the kind of shadow i need (original idea is the courtesy of `css-tricks.com`);

Comment: May this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate/20852489#20852489  `To start, note that z-index on positioned elements and transform by itself create new "stacking contexts" on elements.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `z-index` lower than `-1` to your `card` class.

```
.card {
    z-index:-2;
    position:relative;
}
```

This is because your `z-index` of your `pseudo-elements` is lower than the default `z-index` value of `card`. By default is the `background transparent` and you may see the shadow. When you add a `background-color` then this is positioned above your `pseudo-elements`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/71thws1a/3/

The problem lies in the stacking of css as mentioned by [@Doodlebunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156598/using-pseudoelements-for-box-shadow-z-index-behavior#comment41004295_26156598)

Comment: Can you elaborate, why this doesn't work without `position: relative`?

Comment: @TwiStar  z-index only works on positioned elements (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`) and not on the default `static`