# jQuery adding and removing classes issue on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a Jquery toggle class function which adds and removes the class `flipped` on a click eventListner. [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/rcbayy5x/5/). At the moment this function is working when the user clicks on any of the elements wrapped in the `.card` class. I when want to restrict where the user can click, therefore only allow the click function to work when the user clicks the `.active-btn`.

I have made attempts to do this however once the card is flipped the `active-btn` class doesn't seem to work. by the looks of things the 'front div' is sitting on top of the 'back div Below is a snippet of my code …

```
$('.active-btn').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
            $card = $(this).closest('.card');
            $('.flipped').not($card).removeClass('flipped');
            $card.toggleClass('flipped');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I basically change the `z-index` to `-1` on `.flip .card .face`, and

```
.flip .card {
  -webkit-transform-style: flat;
}
```

The problem with your original is that the perserved-3d keep changing the z-index which causing issues with the order.

[z-index is canceled by setting transform(rotate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate)

Here is the post which goes in more detail.

Comment: global-padding: display: none; hides everything

Comment: meh i don't think that's the case. maybe the case on the prototype i put on jsfiddle but defiantely not the case with the code i have on my local server… the 'front div' is sitting on to of the 'back div'  thanks anyway

Comment: front div' is sitting on top of the 'back div'

Comment: I think I know the issue. If you flip the card, the transform rotate breaks the z-index which makes the "back" comes forward. http://jsfiddle.net/rcbayy5x/10/   is that something you are looking for?

Comment: did you apply position absolute to the front div ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the toggle element, right now the active btn will remove the class and won't add it after.

Do it like this:

```
$( ".active-btn" ).toggle(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
            $card = $(this).closest('.card');
            $('.flipped').not($card).removeClass('flipped');
            $card.toggleClass('flipped');
}, function() {
    e.preventDefault();
            $card = $(this).closest('.card');
            $('.flipped').not($card).addClass('flipped');
            $card.toggleClass('flipped'); );
});
```

Comment: Have you tested your code before put it here ? It doesn't work !

Comment: Because it's a template :) I just gave you a breadcrumb here.

Answer (score 0):

use !hasClass (class has not exist) rather than not,

```
$('.active-btn').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        $card = $(this).closest('.card');
       if (!$('.flipped').hasClass($card)) {
                 removeClass('flipped');
                 $card.toggleClass('flipped');
            }
    });
```