# CSS Z-index active state conflict with input:[type=number]

Tags: css

I have an image set to scale on the active state.  However, i'm having a strange issue which seems to be isolated to Safari where the number dials within the input boxes will not stay behind my image:

[image: Image Overlap]

here is my css for the active state:

```
  .product_front img:active {
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(2.5);
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: It is very likely that your CSS transform is establishing a new stacking context. Have you considered using translation along the z-axis instead of using z-index? Related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate.

Comment: That's probably a bug