# Why does html child element disappears when rotating element in Webkit?

Tags: css, html, rotation, webkit

I am trying to rotate a container div in html so that all of it's child elements rotate with it.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var n = 73; // -58
  var elContainer = document.getElementById('container');
  var elDegrees = document.getElementById('degrees');

  var setAngle = function(n) {
    elContainer.style.transform = ''.concat('rotate(', n, 'deg)');
    elDegrees.innerHTML = n;
  }; // /setAngle()

  document.getElementById('btnUp').addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    n++;
    setAngle(n);
  });

  document.getElementById('btnDown').addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    n--;
    setAngle(n);
  });

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 640, 360);
  };
  img.src = 'https://blog.codepen.io/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Made-For-Codepen.png';
  setAngle(n);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#root {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  transform-origin: center center 0px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#child {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="child">
      TEXT ELEMENT
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="" width="640" height="360"></canvas>
  </div>

</div>

<button id="btnDown">-1 degree</button>
<button id="btnUp">+1 degree</button>
<span id="degrees"></span> degrees

<p>
  In Chrome or Safari, if the container is rotated greater than 73 degrees or less than -58 degrees, to absolute positioned child div with text disappears. Why?
</p>
```

For some reason when the container div is rotated past 73 degrees or -58 degrees in Chrome or Safari, the child div element disappears behind the canvas element. This happens with both canvas elements and video elements. This problem does not happen in Firefox.

Comment: I believe this is the answer to my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the same webkit rotation on the child too? And possibly floating the child might help. Not 100% sure. Or, you may need to specify which browsers you are using within the webkit.

Comment: The child still disappears if you float it. If you apply the same rotation to the child it just dissapears at a later time. Not sure what you mean by "_specify which browsers you are using within the webkit_". By webkit I mean browsers based off of [webkit](https://webkit.org/) like Chrome and Safari.