# Does css transform changes the z-index property?

Tags: css, z-index, css-transforms

I found a wired thing when I apply the transform to an element, it changes the z-index order, the code as:

```
<button class="test">
  click me
</button>
```

css:

```
.test{
  border-radius:100px;
  transition:all 1s;
  position:relative;
}

.test:hover{
  transform:translateY(30px);
}

.test::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/JianNCI/pen/jZQRpz?editors=1100

I was intending to hide the `:: after content by setting the`z-index order to -1 and I am setting the blue background color for distinguishing them. but once I hovering on the button, the hiding content will overlap the button. so my questions are:

1. Why the `z-index:-1`not working when I hovering on it? it is supposed to remain as -1 since I only set the transform property within the hover effect.
2. When I replace the `transform` property like `color: red`, it is work as I expected. So I am wondering if this the `transform` makes the `z-index:-1` lose effect in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [z-index is canceled by setting transform(rotate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate)