# z-index weird behavior?

Tags: css

Given the example below

```js
function clickme() {
  console.log(' button been clicked')
}
```

```css
.d1,
.d2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: -99;
  opacity: .5;
  position: relative;
}

.d2>button {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <button onclick="clickme();">Click Me</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d2">
  <button onclick="clickme();">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Why when the button moves outside it's parent, it become clickable ?

**EDIT:**

I used `transform: translateY(50px);` to move the button, however we can also use `position:relative;top:50px;` to move the button yet the problem still remains.

Comment: `z-index` isn't applied on elements with static (default) positioning. Adding `position: relative;` applies it. As for the transform, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate

Comment: it's not necessarily transform to move the element,we can apply `position:relative;top:50px;`to the button and the same would happen

Comment: I am pretty sure you know that z-index work with position:relative so you can reduce your question to the outside/inside part : why we can click when it's outside and not inside?

Comment: I figured adding that part would explain the question a bit more.

Comment: no, you are focusing on position:relative which not the issue at all .. I suggest you to edit the question so we can understand the main issue and don't focus on z-index and static element

Comment: Suppose now it's much cleaner

Comment: yes now it's better

Comment: @j08691 the question you linked doesn't apply here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are facing a *hidden* issue and translate/opacity has nothing to do here. When using negative `z-index` it's like you made your elements to be behind the `body` (since this one has a `z-index` set to `auto`). Then the `body` height is defined by its in-flow content (both divs) and using translate simply made the element to be placed below the body thus we can reach it and click it.

let's add some border/background to better see the issue:

```js
function clickme() {
  console.log(' button been clicked')
}
```

```css
.d1,
.d2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index:-1;
  position: relative;
}

.d2>button {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}

body {
 background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
 border:2px solid;
}
html {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <button onclick="clickme();">Click Me</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d2">
  <button onclick="clickme();">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

The `body` is the red square, all your element are behind it and the button is moved to the bottom and no more covered by the body. The same will also happen if you move your button using other properties without changing the `body` height.

If you add some height to the body, translate won't change anything as the button will kept behind the `body`

```js
function clickme() {
  console.log(' button been clicked')
}
```

```css
.d1,
.d2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

.d2>button {
  transform: translateY(50px);
}

body {
 height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <button onclick="clickme();">Click Me</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="d2">
  <button onclick="clickme();">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh i see, so it's not an outside parent issue but outside the body, make sense.

Comment: @ZohirSalak not *outside* but no more covered by the body which is still on the top of alll your elements