# Basic Parallax effect defying physics

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I'm trying to understand how parallax works so that I no longer need to rely on code snippets from others and allow me to build more custom effects so what I did is made a very basic document.

A blue box, an orange square. I placed the circle behind the box, applied a tranform effect, alittle bit of CSS and all seems well. The issue I'm running into is this - shouldn't the thing furthest away from the point of view move slower than what it closer? I've played around with the numbers and cannot figure out why the circle is moving faster that the square...

Can someone explain this to me? Am I misunderstanding something?

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="circle"></div>
```

```
#body {
  height: 5000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#box {
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 500px;
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  z-index: -1;
}

#circle {
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  left: 350px;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,-2px) scale(1);
  z-index: 1;
}




 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
  var box = document.querySelector('#box');
  var circle = document.querySelector('#circle');

  box.style.transform = `translate3d(0,${(0 + (scrolled * .75))}px, 0)`;
  circle.style.transform = `translate3d(0,${(0 + (-scrolled * .15))}px, -2px) scale(1)`;
});
```

[Link to my test file](https://codepen.io/Costa3/pen/eYOwyYe)

Thanks!

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851452/z-index-is-canceled-by-setting-transformrotate

Comment: Also, use a passive scroll event-listener to make it less jerky when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The `translate3d( 0, 0, -2px )` transform on the `#circle` means it will always be behind `#square` even when `#circle`'s `z-index` is higher.

Change it to `translate2d` (and remove the `tz` argument) or change it to `translate3d( 0, 0, 0 )`. The same applies to the `scroll` event listener.

That said, you don't need *any* `scroll` event listener. See this example: it does parallax scrolling without using any scripts: https://codepen.io/tribex/pen/mWNWdz